# Javascript: Understanding when a tasked job gets into the stack?

Tags: javascript

```js
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log("Click the button!");
}, 100);
    
console.log("1");
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
console.log("4");
console.log("5");
console.log("6");
console.log("7");
```

I have a question about the event loop and how queued tasks are pushed to the stack in JS.  Given the code above, I have a short setTimeout with a log statement inside.
Following that, let's say I have `console.log()` up from 1 up to 1,000,000 ( only 7 in my code for obvious reasons).

My understanding of what happens is:

1. the setTimeout is added to the call stack
2. it gets popped off the call stack and handled by the Web API which is running the timeout
3. after the 1ms timeout, the timeout is passed to the Task Queue to run once the stack
   is clear.

The event loop then pushes what is in the task queue to the stack once the stack is *clear* and the log inside the timeout is displayed.  What constitutes the stack being clear though?  Since each individual console.log should be added to the stack and popped off immediately, would the queued task manage to sneak into the stack and run before all those numbers logged up to 1,000,000?

```
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log("Click the button!");
}, 100);

console.log("1");
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
console.log("4");
console.log("5");
console.log("6");
console.log("7");  
// pretend console.log all the way up to 1,000,000
```

Comment: yes, your understanding is correct. setTimeout was added to the call stack first and then the next are the log counters from 1 ~1,000,000. After 100ms the log for "Click the button" was added last in to the queue.

The reason why queued task was not inserted between the individual console.log is based on priority, queued task are only returned to the main thread once it's not busy anymore.

Comment: thank you.  When you say "main thread is not busy anymore", what constitutes that though?  What if after all those console logs, there was a separate function call from within that method, ....that timeout STILL waits in the queue?

Comment: That `setTimeout` task will be called when the stack is clear. The stack will be clear when all synchronous code finishes. That includes all `console.log`s, other func calls, and basically everything that doesn't itself queue another task. So, your `setTimeout` will nicely await all your `console.log`s and such things, even if they take 10 seconds to complete

Comment: (to the previous comment) "the main thread isn't busy" means the same as "the stack is empty" in this case...

Comment: thanks so much for taking time to explain this..I'd be happy to choose this as the best answer if you want to make it one rather than a comment.

Comment: @LegoGeo Unfortunately, that's also a very complicated matter since main thread are somehow unreliable and not always performs the same to every device, so it's very difficult to assess when do you know if main thread is not busy anymore in the microscopic level.

But what you can do to understand what the main thread is doing is to assess the page is by using DevTools and go to "Performance" tab and do a "Profile" to the page using script it will show you the timeline together with the call stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the timeout function will be done after every other console.log. Just test the code you wrote.

```js
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log("DONE");
}, 1);

for(let i=0;i<100000;i++)
  console.log(i);
```